# Proving pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I'm having trouble proving: $$f_n(x) = \frac{1-n^2x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}$$

converges pointwise to zero for $x \in \,[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.

**My attempt for finding :** $N(\epsilon,x)$
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1-n^2x^2}{(1+n^{2}x^{2})} - 0\right|<\epsilon &\iff \frac{|1-n^2x^2|}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} < \epsilon\\
\end{align*}

Since,
\begin{align*}
\frac{|1-n^2x^2|}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} &< \frac{|1-n^2x^2|}{n^4x^4}\\
\end{align*}

we can then find $\epsilon$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{|1-n^2x^2|}{n^4x^4}<\epsilon
\end{align*}

I get stuck after this step. Does anyone know how to prove this without using $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HINT*

Let $x \in [-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$

> \begin{align*}
> |f_n(x)| \leq \frac{|1-n^2x^2|}{n^4x^4}\leq\frac{1}{n^4x^4}+\frac{n^2x^2}{n^4x^4}=\frac{1}{n^4x^4}+\frac{1}{n^2x^2}
> \end{align*}

Exists $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all n$\geq n_1$ we have $\frac{1}{n^4x^4} \leq \epsilon\Rightarrow n_1 \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\epsilon}x^4}$

Exists $n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all n$\geq n_2$ we have $\frac{1}{n^2x^2} \leq \epsilon\Rightarrow n_2 \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}x^2}$

Take $N \geq \max\{n_1,n_2\}$ and you are done.

Comment: Is $N(\epsilon,x) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}*x}$?

Comment: @migueldva see my edits

Comment: Thanks for that... but wouldn't the exponents of x be gone? @MariosGrestas

Comment: you are welcome